# Wicket 7 unable to find component in Form tree

Tags: java, forms, wicket

I'm creating a form that allows an admin to edit user information. However, when I run the app, I receive the following error message:

```
Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'editUserFirstname' in [Form [Component id = userEditForm]]
    Expected: 'userEditForm:editUserFirstname'.
    Found with similar names: ''
```

But so far as I can tell, my editUserFirstname field is bounded by th userEditForm.

Here's my code...

**EditUserPage.html**

```
<form wicket:id="userEditForm" class="userEditForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <wicket:message key="userEditLegendKey"></wicket:message>
        </legend>
        <table id="userEditFormTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="editUserFirstname">
                        <wicket:message key="firstnameKey"></wicket:message>
                    </label>
                    <input wicket:id="editUserFirstname" id="editUserFirstname" type="text" size="40"/>
                    <label for="editUserSurname">
                        <wicket:message key="surnameKey"></wicket:message>
                    </label>
                    <input wicket:id="editUserSurname" id="editUserSurname" type="text" size="40"/>
                    <label for="editUserUsername">
                        <wicket:message key="usernameKey"></wicket:message>
                    </label>
                    <input wicket:id="editUserUsername" id="editUserUsername" type="text" size="40"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" wicket:id="savebutton" value="save"/>
                    <input type="submit" wicket:id="cancelbutton" value="cancel">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**EditUserPage.java**

```
public class EditUserPage extends BasePage {
    StringValue ormId;
    Sysuser sysuser;

    /**
     * Constructs ...
     *
     * @param parameters The class page parameters.
     */
    public EditUserPage(PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        ormId = parameters.get("ormId");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        try {
            sysuser = Sysuser.getSysuserByORMID(ormId.toInt());
        } catch (PersistentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Form form = new Form("userEditForm") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
            }
        };

        form.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Object>(this));
        form.add(new TextField("userEditLegendKey").setRequired(true).setLabel(new Model<String>("User Information")));
        form.add(new TextField("firstnameKey").setRequired(true).setLabel(new Model<String>("Firstname")));
        form.add(new TextField("surnameKey").setRequired(true).setLabel(new Model<String>("Surname")));
        form.add(new TextField("usernameKey").setRequired(true).setLabel(new Model<String>("Username")));
        form.add(new Button("savebutton"));

        form.add(new Button("cancelbutton"));
        final FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        add(feedback);

        add(form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the HTML you have `<input wicket:id="editUserFirstname"` and in the Java code `form.add(new TextField("firstnameKey")`. The ids must be the same.